# Login works but doesn't refresh the page

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, authentication

I am working on a laravel inertia with vuejs project doing the login and logout currently but everytime i login or logout i have to refresh the page manually so the profile name is displayed on top or removed ( logout )
here are few code snippets from the project what's the problem

login.vue :

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
        <div class="lg:w-1/3 mx-auto sm:w-1/2 md:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3">
            <div>
                <label for="email" class="label">E-mail</label>
                <input v-model="form.email" type="text" id="email" class="input" />
                <div class="input-error" v-if="form.errors.email">{{form.errors.email}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                <input v-model="form.password" type="password" id="password" class="input" />
                <div class="input-error" v-if="form.errors.password">{{form.errors.password}}</div>

            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <button class="btn-primary w-full" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
    const form = useForm({
        email:null,
        password:null,
    })
    const login = () => form.post(route('login.store'))

</script>
```

mainlayout.vue

```
<template>
    <header
        class="border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 w-full"
    >
        <div class="container mx-auto">
            <nav class="p-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="text-lg font-medium">
                    <Link :href="route('formation.index')">Formations</Link>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="text-xl text-indigo-600 dark:text-indigo-200 font-bold text-center"
                >
                    <Link :href="route('formation.index')"> E-learning </Link>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div v-if="user" class="flex items-center gap-4">
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ user.name }}</div>

                        <div class="btn-primary">
                            <Link :href="route('formation.create')"
                                >+ New formation
                            </Link>
                        </div>

                       <div>
                        <Link :href="route('logout')" method="delete" as="button" @click="logout">
                            Logout

                        </Link>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-else>
                        <Link :href="route('login')">Sign-in</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="container mx-auto p-4 w-full">
        <slot>Default</slot>
    </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { Link, usePage } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
const page = usePage();
const user = computed(() => 
page.props.user);

const logout = async () => {
    await fetch(route('logout'), {
        method: 'DELETE',
    });
    location.reload(); // Reload the page after logging out
}


</script>
```

and finally the store function of the authcontroller

```
public function store(Request $request){

        if(!Auth::attempt($request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]),true)){
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => 'Authentication failed'
            ]);
        };
        $request -> session() -> regenerate();
        return redirect()->intended('/formation');

    }
```

i added location.reload in the logout it worked but the login i didn't find a solution

Comment: form.post will be doing an asynchronous AJAX request I expect (you can confirm by examining your browser's network tool). Async requests initiated by JS don't follow redirect headers, so `return redirect()` will have no effect. Indeed, the whole point of AJAX (and of an SPA framework like inertiajs) is to do everything in the background, without using full page postbacks, reloads or redirects.

Comment: You could read the location header and then load that view using ajax, for example. Or just have the backend return the ID of the item which needs loading. The idea of inertiaJS, as I understand it, is that everything is done on a single page without any full page reloading

Answer (score 0):

most likely the issue is inertia persisted the main layout.
you could add a key to re-render the layout based on the route or any other property (something like a user prop).

```
<template>

 <header :key="currentRoute">

 </header>

</template>



const currentRoute= computed(() => {
 return location.pathname.substr(1)
})
```

For the logout, try using inertia helper without fetch

```
import { router } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

const logout = async () => {
router.delete(route('logout'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot but it's not working. I tried adding it to the main vue but i still have to reload the page manually.